# Допустимо ли тире: "Моя девушка (–) убеждённая извращенка-девственница"?

Tags: пунктуация

Допустимо ли тире в названии аниме "Моя девушка (–) убеждённая извращенка-девственница"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Речь идет о тире между подлежащим и сказуемым, при этом они выражены именами существительными в именительном падеже и между ними нулевая связка. В таких случаях обычно ставится тире: *Тамань – самый скверный городишко из всех приморских городов России (Лермонтов)*.
Из этого правила есть исключения, в частности тире не ставится в простых предложениях разговорного стиля: *Моя мать учительница*. Розенталь пишет, что отсутствие тире отражает "произношение с логическим ударением на сказуемом" (ср.: *Моя сестра — учительница* — ударение и на слове сестра, и на слове учительница).

Так что в вашем случае тире несомненно **допустимо**. Вопрос может стоять лишь о том, допустимо ли отсутствие тире. Я бы поставил тире.